# Remove specific red underline in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

There are a lot of questions about this, but most of the answers I found is how to permantly remove red underlines (warnings), but I want to remove a red underline from a specific line, how can I do that?

[This is the warning I want to remove.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zY8h.png)

Comment: this means you don't have this include file, so if you compile you get an error

Comment: @rioV8 It's a kernel module, the header file is located somewhere else in the kernel

Comment: then modify your `cpp_properties.json`